# How to use columns BY and OR in Google sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, reserved-words

Currently I use Google Sheets as a database, which has more than 1000 columns from A to AGH. If the query contains column BY or column OR, the result will be null.

How can I avoid that column names cannot be mixed with query commands (by and or) ?

Comment: You can use `=QUERY({A:AGH},"select Col1, Col77, Col408")` Col177 for `BY` and Col408 for `OR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in  [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#identifiers):

> Identifiers (or IDs) are text strings that identify columns.

> Important: If your identifier

> Has spaces,
> Is a reserved word,
> Contains anything but alphanumeric characters or underscores ([a-zA-Z0-9_]), or
> Starts with a digit

> it must be surrounded by back-quotes (not single quotes).

```
=QUERY(BY1:BY4,"SELECT `BY`",0)
```

Alternatively, `{}` removes the range references and only puts the values, which can be referenced with `Col` numbers.

```
=QUERY({BY1:BY4},"SELECT Col1",0)
```

Comment: Learn something new.

Comment: [`````](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2K5jinAlChoCLS/giphy.gif)                 -@TheMaster